# Windows NT planned shutdown

Tags: windows

I have a demand to restart or shutdown Windows NT at certain time, or it can be after certain time. Something like I can do in command line > shutdown /r /t 1800.
Issue is that some computers needs to be off few times per night.

Can this be made in regedit somehow? It is not possible to install any software new and no access to outer Internet(viruses).
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Windows NT 4.x has a basic task scheduling service which you can use through the [`at` command](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/313565/how-to-use-the-at-command-to-schedule-tasks).

```
at 18:00 /every:M,T,W,Th,F,S,Su "shutdown /r /t 60 /f"
```

(You might first need to enable the service through Control Panel, and make sure it starts on every boot.)